# Excel - VLOOKUP issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this:

[image]

My issue:

in column F2 I want R2 -> IF -> B2+C2+D2 exists in O:O;P:P;Q:Q
but I do not know how to use VLOOKUP with multiple columns

my attemp was '`=VLOOKUP(B2;O:O;4;FALSE)`' and I do not know why I used 4... cuz I count R2 as index 4 from O2...

Answer (score 1):

This is just a multiple column lookup. While two column lookups are more common, three column lookups are not that rare.

```
=index(r:r, aggregate(15, 6, row($2:$999)/((o$2:o$999=b2)*(p$2:p$999=c2)*(q$2:q$999=d2)), 1))
```

That will return the value from column R for the first matching set of columns O:Q. In the case of multiple matches, you could return the last match by changing 15 to 14.

Since your returned results are expected to be numeric, a sumifs could also be used.

```
=sumifs(r:r, o:o, b2, p:p, c2, q:q, d2)
```

However this would return skewed results is more than a single match was found.

In your own vlookup, the 4 represents the fourth column of your lookup range. Since you were only providing a single column (e.g. O:O), you would never return the value from column R without changing the lookup range to O:R.

Comment: OP has to change the separator to a « ; » but two neat methods.

Comment: Good point; I missed the `;` regional system list separators.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach (since they look like dates DD/MM/YYYY) would be to convert each group of three columns to dates

```
=INDEX(R:R,MATCH(DATE(D2,C2,B2),INDEX(DATE(Q:Q,P:P,O:O),0),0))
```

@Jeeped is right to point out that this is slow on full columns, so plz use a formula like

```
=INDEX(R$1:R$100,MATCH(DATE(D2,C2,B2),INDEX(DATE(Q$1:Q$100,P$1:P$100,O$1:O$100),0),0))
```

and adjust the ranges to include your data.

Comment: That array formula is going to be pretty slow if the full column ranges are not cut down to an approximation of the actual data range.

Answer (score 0):

If O:O;P:P;Q:Q is unique, you can use:

```
=lookup(1,0/((O:O=B2)*(P:P=C2)*(Q:Q=D2), R:R)
```